I want to know the next cron expression start time using CronExpression.next. But it doesn't work as I expected
ZonedDateTime next = CronExpression.parse("0 0 1 ? * 1")
        .next(new Date().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Seoul")));
   System.out.println("next = " + next);

next = 2024-04-15T01:00+09:00[Asia/Seoul]
It is a croon ceremony that starts every Sunday at 1 o'clock.
However, the ZonedDateTime above always shows Monday.
please tell me why

Does this answer your question? Can't use Spring-context's cronExpression with ZonedDateTime

no
It runs well.
However, the expected value of "0 0 1 ? * 1" is the next scheduled date of execution of this croon tab is 2024-04-14T01:00+09:00[Asia/Seoul] Sunday, but the problem is that it always comes out on Monday 2024-04-15T01:00+09:00[Asia/Seoul].

Looks like 0 0 1 ? * 1 schedules it on Monday. while 0 0 1 ? * 0 schedules it on Sunday (0 based index where 0 is Sunday). You can use sites like https://crontab.cronhub.io/ (not endorsed) to verify your cron expressions

As suggested in comments also, try 0 0 1 ? * 0 this expression, where last 0 indicates Sunday.
